# How to Skip preview page (step 4 ) and redirect the user to Thank you page(Step 5) in Django-Oscar

Tags: django, payment-gateway, django-oscar, stripe-payments

I have been working on django-oscar, where i am integrating stripe prebuilt checkout page, i want to be able to achieve any one of this 2 scenarios,

**Scenario 1:**
How to skip step 4(Preview) and redirect the user to the step 5(Thank you) without clicking on the "Place order" button on Preview page ?
i.e on clicking on the "pay" button in stripe checkout page, i want to be able to call "submit" method of PaymentDetailsView.
the rest functionality should work as it is.

**Scenario 2:**
How to make the preview page first and then the payment page after preview ?

Please If you can just give me an overview of what methods i need to overwrite to achieve any one of this 2 scenarios, that would be helpful for me.

Let me know if you need more explanation or you want to see what i have done yet ?

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, the steps are found in `templates/oscar/checkout/nav.html`, you open that `nav.html` and then you can edit it by removing the step that you want to skip.